# Win32 C++: Display contents of a listbox

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox

I am trying to display the contents of a listbox using the SendMessage function. However when I press the button to execute the piece of code below, I get the following segfault in my code when I call

```
SendMessage(hwndLBox,LB_GETTEXT,k,(LPARAM)lBoxitems);
```

Segfault (dbgheap.c):

```
extern "C" _CRTIMP int __cdecl _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(
        const void * pUserData
        )
 {
        if (!pUserData)
            return FALSE;

        if (!_CrtIsValidPointer(pHdr(pUserData), sizeof(_CrtMemBlockHeader), FALSE))
            return FALSE;

        return HeapValidate( _crtheap, 0, pHdr(pUserData) );
}
```

The Code that causes this segfault:

```
            else if(LOWORD(wParam)==ID_BUTTON_CALC){

                int getLboxitems = SendMessage(hwndLBox,LB_GETCOUNT,NULL,NULL);

                char * lBoxitems = new char[getLboxitems];

                for(unsigned int k=0; k < getLboxitems; k++){
                        SendMessage(hwndLBox,LB_GETTEXT,k,(LPARAM)lBoxitems);
                        MessageBox(hwnd,lBoxitems,"Listbox says",NULL);
                }

                delete[] lBoxitems;
            }
```

I am using Visual Studio Beta 2011 to compile my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate space for your strings. `char * lBoxitems = new char[getLboxitems];` allocates a char array that is the size of how many items you have in the list.
The following should work I think:

```
else if(LOWORD(wParam)==ID_BUTTON_CALC)
{
    int getLboxitems = SendMessage(hwndLBox, LB_GETCOUNT, NULL, NULL);

    char ** lBoxitems = new char*[getLboxitems];

    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < getLboxitems; k++)
    {
        int textlength = SendMessage(control, LB_GETTEXTLEN, (WPARAM)k, NULL);
        lBoxitems[k] = new char[textlength + 1]; // +1 for null terminator
        SendMessage(hwndLBox, LB_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)k, (LPARAM)lBoxitems[k]);
        MessageBox(hwnd, lBoxitems[k], "Listbox says" , NULL);
    }
    for (unsigned int k = 0; k < getLboxitems; k++)
    {
        delete [] lBoxitems[k];
    }
    delete[] lBoxitems;
}
```

However, using `std::vector<std::vector<char>>` or `std::vector<std::string>` would be easier:

```
else if(LOWORD(wParam)==ID_BUTTON_CALC)
{
    int getLboxitems = SendMessage(hwndLBox, LB_GETCOUNT, NULL, NULL);

    std::vector<std::string> v(getLboxitems);

    for(unsigned int k = 0; k < getLboxitems; k++)
    {
        int textlength = SendMessage(control, LB_GETTEXTLEN, (WPARAM)k, NULL);
        v[k].resize(textlength + 1);
        std::string& buff = v[k];
        SendMessage(hwndLBox, LB_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)k, (LPARAM)&buff[0]);
        MessageBox(hwnd, v[k].c_str(), "Listbox says" , NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I have been looking for! The code that I am inputting this to will go into my algorithm that requires strings. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see

1. Have you verified that getLboxitems is a valid value (i.e. neither <= 0) or absurdly large ?
2. I don't think you are using arrays properly in this case. You create a dynamic-sized array the size of getLboxitems meaning that if you have 5 items in your list box, you will effectively create an array of five char (and not char* or char[] as you assume you are doing). You would need to create your array this way:

   ```
   // verify with MSDN that 255 is large enough
   char* lBoxitems[255] = new char[getLboxitems][255];
   for(unsigned int k=0; k < getLboxitems; k++) {
       SendMessage(hwndLBox, LB_GETTEXT, k, (LPARAM)(lBoxitems[k]));
       MessageBox(hwnd, lBoxitems[k], "Listbox says", NULL);
   }
   ```

Beware, untested code.

Edit: Thanks to Jesse Good for correction.

Also I would like to point out that this method is not very C++-y. You may want to use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of 2D arrays and only use a temporary array to be used in SendMessage().

Comment: Odd, I've never seen the formatting act up like that. Maybe it's the numbered list or something. I put in a less elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks ! I even tried copy-pasting the code into notepad and back again in here to make it lose any format it would pick up in the background (like in MS Office) but it didn't work :|

Comment: Ah, it was indeed the list. You need 4 extra spaces.

Comment: `char* lBoxitems = new char[getLboxitems][255];` should be `char (*lBoxitems)[255] = new char[getLboxitems][255];`

Comment: I was aware that getLboxitems uses an index which can be negative. Initially I thought the char array took in the entire string which I mistaken for.